# Read txt files untill second blank line

Tags: r, data.table, readr

I wanna read a lot of *.txt files, but only rows untill first blank line.

*.txt example file:

```
structure(c("class1", "class2", NA, "tot", NA, "x", "y", NA, 
"z", "5", "10", NA, "15", NA, "2", "7", NA, "4"), dim = c(9L, 
2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("col1", "col2")))
```

desired output:

```
structure(c("class1", "class2", NA, "tot", "5", "10", NA, "15"
), dim = c(4L, 2L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("col1", "col2")))
```

How can I use readr or data.table for to do this?

Thanks all

Comment: Could you share an example that describes one of those text files? Or is the `dput()` output literally the file content?

Comment: What does your txt file look like, you mention "empty lines", are the lines empty or just the values. How are the columns seperated/what is the delimiter. Just show us the content of the text file. Also your desired output is not completely clear, as that would assume you want to stop reading when the **second** "empty" line starts and not before.

Comment: `na1 <- which(rowSums(!is.na(mtx)) == 0); if (length(na1)) mtx <- mtx[1:(na1[1]-1),]` works for me. Why tag with [tag:data.table] and [tag:readr] when your dataset are matrices?